# Is there any relation between the two Mahou Tsukai ni Taisetsu na Koto series?

Tags: somedays-dreamers

In 2003, there was an anime called Mahou Tsukai ni Taisetsu na Koto. In 2008, there another anime called Mahou Tsukai ni Taisetsu na Koto: Natsu no Sora.

I only saw the 2008 one, so I don't really know much about the 2003 one. They both seem to be about young girls who are learning magic, but is there any actual relation between the two series? For example, are there any subtle hints indicating that the 2008 series takes place X years after the original series? Or are there any characters that appear in both series? Or is the only relation that they have similar stories?

(I had to use the English title for the tags since the Japanese title is too long...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Someday's Dreamers: Summer Skies* is basically the second season of Someday's dreamers made by another studio (Hal Film Maker) with a different staff. All it shares with the original is the fictional Tokyo backdrop, as as all characters and most of the setting have changed.

You don't need to watch the first one in order to enjoy the second one.

Comment: Yeah, I never saw the first one but really enjoyed the second one anyway.